# Wamp 5.1 and wamp 5.3 on same machine?

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I want to install wamp 5.1 and wamp 5.3 on same machine. My operating system is Windows XP.

I have initially wamp 5.3. So, i installed wamp5.1. But, I am unable to find wamp 5.3.

How can i install both version versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy answer from the top of my head, install a virtual machine and the other WAMP server on it. Then you can configure shared folders and access the VM Server from the host browser.